# Efficient implementation of AND in databases-like data structure

Tags: database, data-structures

I can imagine how to implement a simple database and index over some columns - simply keep that columns values in a balanced tree of some sort.

What this question is about, is how would `AND` queries be efficiently implemented? How would you implement something like

```
SELECT * FROM points WHERE x > 0 and x < 4 and y > 10 and y < 14
```

Note that I'm not asking specifically about database, but rather of which data structure would be best for this in practice, for two dimensional queries. I remember studying once about [Range Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree) - is this the real world solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can very efficiently do that with a regular search tree...

you can also do this in an O(N), scan over the entire data, which is what i guess most DBs do most of the time. especially considering the cost of indexes.

any way this is the most common and simple kind of indexes, supported in most DBs: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree so if you are looking for a range in the index its relatively easy to optimize...

By the way consider also that you are expecting the DB to understand you are looking for ranges and optimize according to that, because AND usually symbolises that you are just requiring two conditions....